Does conditioning on multiple independent criteria increase the expected value of the common factor?
I'm trying to tackle something for my thesis in Economics.
I Have a model with $A\sim\operatorname N(0,1),$ workers permanent abiliity. $\varepsilon_1,\varepsilon_2 \sim\operatorname N(0,1),$ "noise" to workers ability. $A,\varepsilon_1,\varepsilon_2$ are independent.
In each period $(t)$ workers are promoted from the easy to hard job (there are only two jobs) if $\hat A_t = A+εt > A^*.$ at $t=1$ all of the workers are in the easy job, meaning: in $t=2,$ workers in the hard job are those who for them: $A+ε_1 > A^*.$ Here comes the twist, the firm can depromote workers from the hard to the easy job: at $t=3$ workers in the hard job are only those who for them $(A+ε_1>A^*) \wedge (A+ε_2>A^*).$ Looking at the same cohort of workers, I'm trying to prove that the expected value of workers who in the hard job in $t=3$ is bigger than workers in the hard job in $t=3,$ so:
\begin{align}
& \operatorname E[A\mid (A+ε_1>A^*) \wedge (A+ε_2>A^*)] \\[6pt] > {} & \operatorname E[A\mid (A+ε_1>A^*)]
\end{align}
Is this true? am I missing something? tried many many times to prove it using hazard rates and what's not. Thanks!

Welcome to CV, Sharon.  This site utilizes MathJax markup: enclose your $\TeX$ expressions in dollar signs, $$.$ // When you reframe the first condition as $A-A^*\gt \max(-\varepsilon_1,-\varepsilon_2),$ the route to a solution should become apparent.

A−A∗>max(−ε1,−ε2)
How's that make the solution apparent? Tried many stuff but couldn't solve it.

The maximum of two values can never be any less than the first value.

Sure, but I'm failing to understand how's that helps me say anything on E[A] between the periods? Thanks alot!

I find it helpful to sketch a scatterplot of data from the $(A+\varepsilon_1,A)$ distribution.
